# what's try method means in java?

Tags: java, mybatis

It comes from https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html.

```
try (SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession()) {
   // do work
}
```

when I copy the code into editior .
I get an error

> try with resources are not supported at language level 5

how comes the problem?

Comment: Also have a look at the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: As for the "not supported at language level 5", that sounds like an IDE problem to me. Make sure you've configured your project to use Java 7 or later.

Comment: I fixed the problem by add <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build> to pom.xml for maven . not sure what's that but It works for me.

Comment: It means you're targeting Java 8. Your IDE probably read the `pom.xml` file and auto-configured itself for development in Java 8.